# How to handle or catch server not responding error?

Tags: asp.net, exception, timeout, webserver

I want to catch the server not responding or timed out error. i was using `PageMethods` for calling a function in the serverside from javascript in asp.net web application. some times the server will not respond, so i want to handle that server not responding when i called *PageMethods* from the javascript which is located in aspx file.

please do the needful, thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple try catch would solve your problem

```
try {
    PageMethods.MyMethod();
}
catch(exception){
    //error occured
}
finally {
    //some tidying up
}
```

[javascript try catch reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: hi.. i used this.. its working fine if any error occured like when 'myMethod()' doesnot exit in code behind ..

Comment: can u give me a suggession how to test this time out while debugging in developer environment(in my computer as client and server both are same), i.e., not after publishing on server..

Comment: In your method write a `Thread.Sleep(100*1000)` Sleep for 100 seconds. Default script timeout is 90 seconds.